# How to store an array into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a way to store an array into mysql field? I'm creating a comment rating system so I want to store the arrays of user ids to prevent multiple votings. I'm going to create new table that holds the comment id and the array of user ids who have voted on this comment. Than I'll join comments table and this table and check whether the current user id exists in the voters array or note. If it does than the voting icons would be disabled. I think I'll prevent to use mysql query in loop in this way.

Do you happen to know any better ways?

Comment: I know it's an easy task to prevent multiple votings from one user but I need to display disabled icons for the users that has already voted on the particular comment and use as few mysql queries as possible. As I see the serialize function will handle this problem...

Comment: Is there any reason why you think that will be difficult if you were to use the normalized approach?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo What do you mean in normalized approach?

Comment: It's the approach that @Pekka, @Björn, @Dennis, and myself have suggested in the answers. We're basically suggesting against serializing an array into a single database field, in favour of using another table (called an intersection table) to store your relationships. More details in the answers :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [array in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896485/array-in-mysql)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can always serialize the array and store that in the database.
[PHP Serialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

You can then unserialize the array when needed.

Comment: This breaks the relational model.

Comment: This was perfect for my situation.  Just trying to store a variable array for user settings.  Thanks grant.

Comment: This may make more sense depending on how you are going to access this data later. If you don't need one particular item from the array at a time but only the whole array (which is what I wanted) this solution is just fine.

Comment: Serializing is bad practice... Depending on third parties to read or write to DB makes it a lot less portable open for migration. As stated it defeats the model of a DB. If this is required json_encode could be better solution as it seems to be faster. It also render searches and queries a lot more heaver and hard. If the arrays are smalls implode and explode would work quite well.

Answer (score 66):

You may want to tackle this as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    comment_id int, 
    body varchar(100), 
    PRIMARY KEY (comment_id)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int, 
    username varchar(20), 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comments_votes (
    comment_id int, 
    user_id int, 
    vote_type int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (comment_id, user_id)
);
```

The composite [primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) `(comment_id, user_id)` on the [intersection table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_table) `comments_votes` will prevent users from voting multiple times on the same comments.

Let's insert some data in the above schema:

```
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (1, 'first comment');
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (2, 'second comment');
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (3, 'third comment');

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'user_a');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'user_b');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'user_c');
```

Now let's add some votes for user 1:

```
INSERT INTO comments_votes VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO comments_votes VALUES (2, 1, 1);
```

The above means that user 1 gave a vote of type 1 on comments 1 and 2.

If the same user tries to vote again on one of those comments, the database will reject it:

```
INSERT INTO comments_votes VALUES (1, 1, 1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

If you will be using the [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innodb) storage engine, it will also be wise to use [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) constraints on the `comment_id` and `user_id` fields of the intersection table. However note that [MyISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myisam), the default storage engine in MySQL, does not enforce foreign key constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    comment_id int, 
    body varchar(100), 
    PRIMARY KEY (comment_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int, 
    username varchar(20), 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE comments_votes (
    comment_id int, 
    user_id int, 
    vote_type int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (comment_id, user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (comment_id) REFERENCES comments (comment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

These foreign keys guarantee that a row in `comments_votes` will never have a `comment_id` or `user_id` value that doesn't exist in the `comments` and `users` tables, respectively. Foreign keys aren't required to have a working relational database, but they are definitely essential to avoid broken relationships and orphan rows (ie. [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)).

In fact, referential integrity is something that would have been very difficult to enforce if you were to store serialized arrays into a single database field.

Comment: This should be the one validated answer.

Answer (score 13):

Consider normalizing the table structure into a comments, and a separate votes table.

Table "comments":

```
id
comment
user
...
```

Table "votes":

```
user_id  
comment_id
vote (downvote/upvote)
```

this would allow an unlimited number of votes without having to deal with the limits of a database field.

Also, you may have future needs for operations like "show all votes a user has cast", removing specific votes or limiting the maximum number of votes per day. These operations are dead easy and fast to implement with a normalized structure, and horribly slow and complex in a serialized array.

Comment: The whole point of the OP's question, is probably to avoid using multiple tables.

Answer (score 5):

you should have three tables: users, comments and comment_users.

comment_users has just two fields: fk_user_id and fk_comment_id

That way you can keep your performance up to a maximum :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer to normalize your table structure more, something like;

```
COMMENTS
-------
id (pk)
title
comment
userId


USERS
-----
id (pk)
name
email


COMMENT_VOTE
------------
commentId (pk)
userId (pk)
rating (float)
```

Now it's easier to maintain! And MySQL only accept one vote per user and comment.

Answer (score 1):

create table like this,

```
CommentId    UserId
---------------------
   1            usr1
   1            usr2
```

In this way you can check whether the user posted the comments are not..
Apart from this there should be tables for `Comments` and `Users` with respective id's

Answer (score 1):

If you just store the data in a database as you would if you were manually putting it into an array

```
"INSERT INTO database_name.database_table (`array`)
    VALUES
    ('One,Two,Three,Four')";
```

Then when you are pulling from the database, use the explode() function

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database_name.database_table");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($numrows != 0){
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $array_from_db = $rows['array'];
    }
}else{
    echo "No rows found!".mysql_error();
}
$array = explode(",",$array_from_db);
foreach($array as $varchar){
    echo $varchar."<br/>";
}
```

Like so!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php serialize function to store array in MySQL.

```
<?php

$array = array("Name"=>"Shubham","Age"=>"17","website"=>"http://mycodingtricks.com");

$string_array = serialize($array);

echo $string_array;

?>
```

It’s output will be :

```
a:3{s:4:"Name";s:7:"Shubham";s:3:"Age";s:2:"17";s:7:"website";s:25:"http://mycodingtricks.com";}
```

And then you can use the php unserialize function to decode the data.

I think you should visit [this page on storing array in mysql](https://web.archive.org/web/20160730213347/mycodingtricks.com/php/store-array-in-mysql/).

Answer (score 0):

You can save your array as a json.
there is documentation for json data type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score -1):

Storing with [json](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.json-encode.php) or [serialized](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.serialize.php) array is the best solution for now.
With some situations (trimming " ' characters) json might be getting trouble but serialize should be great choice.

Note: If you change serialized data manually, you need to be careful about character count.