# How do I put this multidimensional array into a SQL-DB cell?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [tennis] => Array
        (
            [3] => Seattle
            [4] => WA
            [5] => 98109
        )

    [Middle East] => Array
        (
            [6] => 2066822513
            [7] => 34740 - Georgetown Keg - 1/2 Manny Pale
            [0] => Hello World
        )

    [Florida] => Array
        (
            [1] => 38380 - Thirteen Coins-Boren
            [2] => 125 Boren Ave N
            [3] => Seattle
        )

)
```

I am looking for a way to best store it into one single cell in my SQL-DB. The keys of the main array (tennis, middle east, florida) have to be kept. The other keys of the subarrays can be omitted. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store an array into mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413291/how-to-store-an-array-into-mysql) - and [the many other duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+store+array%23).

Comment: I got it. please check my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about the serialize function, and implemented it.

The solution: First I turn the array into a string:

> $array = serialize($array);

Then I store the string into the DB cell.

To get back the array, I unserialize the string from the DB cell:

> $array = unserialize($array);

And I end up with the same array. Simple

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) function.

Comment: thank you penartur. I've done that and posted a detailed solution

Answer (score 0):

I would use JSON since it's more universal.

```
<?php
  $json=addslashes(json_encode($array));
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES ('$json')");
?>
```

For really large blobs you could do `gzdeflate()` in that case I recommend also saving a checksum.