# Array conversion to store in array in databse

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store an array into mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413291/how-to-store-an-array-into-mysql)

This is an array that i need to store in databse:-

```
$v=array(
"Image"=> array (
                 0=> array (
                                "id"=> 150,
                                "Tags"=> array(
                                                0=> array ( "id"=> 200, "text"=>"John Doe", "left"=> 250, "top"=> 50, "url"=> "person.php?id=200" ,"isDeleteEnable"=> true ),
                                                1=> array ( "id"=> 400, "text"=> "Michael Smith", "left"=> 420, "top"=> 45, "width"=> 120, "height"=> 120, "isDeleteEnable"=> true ),
                                                2=> array ( "id"=> 500, "text"=> "Peter Parker" ,"left"=> 55 ,"top"=> 40, "url"=> "person.php?id=500" ,"isDeleteEnable"=> false )
                                                )
                            )

                   )       

    ) ;
```

Is there any function which can do this, so that this whole array can be stored in database.
I am developing on LAMP.
Also i need retrieve this array again from database.

Comment: u want to store this array into one filed of table ?

Comment: I think you have to code your own custom function

Comment: I think serializing the data is a very bad idea. Make a decent normalized table/fields structure, and store each element in its own field.

Comment: Especially if you need to store more than one record like this and you need to retrieve the right one

Comment: Please use the search, this has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

```
$db = serialize($v);
```

And, of course, [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to restore it.

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/MMYoR) (using the data you've provided)

Comment: With serialize one can store any data in a table with 1 field. Why do whe have databases at all?

Comment: @JvdBerg: Without knowing more about the OPs project, the information may be session related or dynamic and not lend itself to a formal database structure. Conversely they could be working within a database that cannot be changed but provides additional custom fields that allow additional information to be stored without affecting the schema. Either way, it's not my place to judge implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.  Most notably, you can [serialize it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and store the serialized string in the database, then use `unserialize` to turn the string back into an array.  This is the most straightforward answer.

The other option is to setup your database to support exactly what you're doing by having a table `image` with field 'id', and table `imagetag`  with fields like `imageid` and `tagid`, and table `tag` with fields like `id` and `text`.

This option is more modular and better managed by your database management system.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = serialize($v);
$v = unserialize($string);
```