# Store Session Array in Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the array-ed session....

```
$_SESSION['Names'] = array (11,15,26);
$_SESSION['Location'] = array (35,42,10);
```

and I want to store them in my database...

```
$que = "Insert into tblpeople (DateTimePosted, first, second, third) VALUES(now(),'$_SESSION['Names'][0], $_SESSION['Location'][0])','$_SESSION['Names'][1], $_SESSION['Location'][1])','$_SESSION['Names'][2], $_SESSION['Location'][2])')";
$exec = mysql_query($que);
```

After Saving, my database (tblpeople) shows the following values:

**DateTimePosted:** *2014-01-03 16:23:02*

**first:**  *Array[0],Array[0]*

**second:** *Array[1],Array[1]*

**third:** *Array[2],Array[2]*

Instead, I want my output to be...

**DateTimePosted:** *2014-01-03 16:23:02*

**first:**  *11,35*

**second:** *15,42*

**third:** *26,10*

What's wrong?

Comment: there is extra `)` at the end of session values

Comment: like how? I don't get it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413291/how-to-store-an-array-into-mysql

Comment: It seems that your table is not properly normalized; numerically named columns are a sign of sql anti-pattern.

Comment: You need to wrap the variables in curly braces; i.e. `"...'{$_SESSION['Names'][0]}', ..."`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand multidimensional arrays in a string, you need to wrap them in curly braces:

```
$que = "Insert into tblpeople (DateTimePosted, first, second, third)
        VALUES(now(),
               '{$_SESSION['Names'][0]}, {$_SESSION['Location'][0]}',
               '{$_SESSION['Names'][1]}, {$_SESSION['Location'][1]}',
               '{$_SESSION['Names'][2]}, {$_SESSION['Location'][2]}')";
```

You also had some extra parentheses in the values.

However, this seems like a pretty strange way to store data into a database. Why do you have two values separated by commas in each column, rather than splitting each into separate columns? And why are you storing array elements into different columns, rather than using separate tables with each value in a row?

Answer (score 0):

use this function

```
$x=serialize($_SESSION['Names']);
```

it return a string that you can save any where

and this function reverse it

```
$_SESSION['Names']=unserialize($x);
```

Comment: and i should store it as $x[0] instead of $_SESSION['Names'][0]? Is that what you mean?

Comment: `serialize/unserialize` has vulnerability, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection. `json_encode/json_decode` will be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['Names'] = array (11,15,26);
$_SESSION['Location'] = array (35,42,10);


$refNumbers = $_SESSION['Names'];
$partIds = $_SESSION['Location'];



$combined = array();

foreach($refNumbers as $index => $refNumber) {
    if(!array_key_exists($index, $partIds)) {
        throw OutOfBoundsException();
    }

    $combined[] = array(
        'Names'  => $refNumber,
        'Location' => $partIds[$index]
    );
}

print_r($combined);

$combine1 = implode(",",$combined[0]);
$combine2 = implode(",",$combined[1]);
$combine3 = implode(",",$combined[2]);



$que = "insert into tblpeople (DateTimePosted, first, second, third) VALUES(now(),'$combine1','$combine2','$combine3')";
//$exec = mysql_query($que);

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have already solved this problem but anyway, please don't delete your answer. It may be helpful to some who may land on this question :)