# SQL Architecture design

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have the following tables:

```
+---+---------+ 
|id |   name  |    foreign_key1 = this table's id
+---+---------+  
|1  |   White |
|2  |   Black |
+---+---------+

+----+------+-------------+
|id  | name | foreign_key1|    
+----+------+-------------+
|1   | Grey | 1           |
|2   | Grey | 2           |       
+----+------+-------------+
```

Is there a way that I could persist the last table's information with only one row? So that table could represent that grey is both white and black in one row?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [array-like column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413291/how-to-store-an-array-into-mysql) (string) and make it a one row record, but I wouldn't suggest that, it's better to have them as separate rows. Your approach is fine, but I'll suggest (if I've understood your idea) a little different schema:
You can make two tables: Colors, and Related_Colors, like this:

```
    Colors
+---+---------+
|id |   name  |
+---+---------+
|1  |   White |
|2  |   Black |
|3  |   Gray  |
+---+---------+

      Related_Colors
+---+---------+---------+
|id |color1_id|color2_id|
+---+---------+---------|
|1  |3        |1        |
|2  |3        |2        |
+---+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could; it's called denormalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). Essentially you would need to create (in the second table) a column for each one of the possible IDs in the first table. So the schema of the second table would be:

```
ID
Name
White
Black
```

This also explains why you probably should not do it; what happens when you want to add another ID in the first table (e.g. purple)? As things are you would just need to add another row in table 1, and reference it from the relevant rows. If you denormalize this way, you would need to change the schema to accommodate the new possible value. The new column would of course be empty for most rows.

Another possibility would be to maintain the values as a concatenated string; so the schema would be

```
ID
Name
List Of IDs From Table1
```

And in this case the last field would contain White, Black. The drawback of this approach is that you can no longer query efficiently by the values from table1. (You can't properly index that field)

Ultimately the question is - what are your needs. If you need to read rows quickly, and have them in a 'reporting friendly' format, denormalization may work for you. But in most DB design cases it would not be required.